# Call TranslateMessage from .NET in an IMessageFilter

Tags: c#, winapi, xna, pinvoke

I am creating a game in XNA and am looking to implement proper input-handling, which XNA lacks to a ridiculous degree. I have a class that implements `IMessageFilter` to intercept Window Messages and pass them along to `TranslateMessage` as a normal message pump would (but not XNA's, of course).

The part where I am stuck/unsure is how to to go from the `System.Windows.Forms.Message` that `IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage(ref Message)` gives, to the `struct tagMSG {...}` that Windows API uses.

Now I can use P/Invoke as such:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct MSG
    {
        public IntPtr   hwnd;
        public int      message;
        public IntPtr   wParam;
        public IntPtr   lParam;
        public uint     time;
        public int      pointX;
        public int      pointY;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool TranslateMessage([In] ref MSG m);
```

But the thing is that `Message` does not contain a definition for either `time` or `POINT` as required for the Windows Message.

My questions are the following:

1. Can I fill in 0 for `time`, `pointX` and `pointY` and have TranslateMessage still working properly?
2. I have seen other code that uses `Marshal.StructureToPtr` to copy the `Message` structure and pass that directly to `TranslateMessage`. Does `Message` contain hidden fields in the correct layout order? Because MSDN and Object Browser only give me the properties, and from those I should conclude that it is missing `time` and `POINT` and that the order is wrong.

So, what is the best way to pass the message to `TranslateMessage` so it can create those much wanted `WM_CHAR`'s for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to test question 2 by writing a simple program and these are the results:

On Win32 `struct MSG` is 28 bytes and `Message` is 20 bytes. `Message` adds a field `result` which is an `IntPtr`, but lacks the `time` and `POINT` fields.

Using either `struct MSG` or `Message` with `Marshal.StructureToPtr` + zeroing out the remaining 8 bytes yields the same results. Both have same `hwnd`, `message`, `wparam` and `lparam` and for both the rest of the properties are 0.

The conclusion is that `Message` does contain the first few members in the correct order, but since it is too small it is not safe to directly be used. However, the lack of crashing of a test program using the naive implementation seems to suggest that `TranslateMessage` does not look at the missing fields, but this is conjecture.

As for question 1, it seems to work without issue: `TranslateMessage` generates the correct `WM_CHAR` messages. I assume as long as the application doesn't use the `time` or `POINT` fields it should work.